# Micro-ROS on ESP32 without external agent?

Tags: ros, ros2, embedded

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're evaluating Micro-ROS for use in our existing ESP32-based product.  One of our requirements is that our bot must be able to function without network access and so must be completely self-contained (no external agent).  (We're new to the (micro) ROS world but our understanding is that each sensor/actuator requires a separate node, multiple of of which can run on the MCU, but must publish/subscribe via an external agent running on a separate (linux) box.)

[This thread](https://discourse.ros.org/t/microros-without-ros2-agent/13984) discusses P2P functionality using an embedded agent with `CedMiddleware`, but it sounds like only NuttX can run such an agent, with support for other RTOSs on the road map.

Is it possible to do what we want with current Micro-ROS?  If not, is there a rough timeframe for when this would be supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370306/micro-ros-on-esp32-without-external-agent?/) by [MisterEd](https://answers.ros.org/users/68686/mistered/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-01-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi MisterEd, micro-ROS team speaking here.

To date, there is an alternative P2P implementation that, unlike the one using the CedMiddleware Agent, realizes a *true* brokerless P2P functionality (find the relevant branches [here](https://github.com/eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Client/tree/feature/brokerless_p2p) and [here](https://github.com/micro-ROS/rmw-microxrcedds/tree/feature/brokerless_p2p)). It is still prototypical, but we have already successfully tested it on ESP32 boards connected over WiFi and using Best-Effort communication mode. This solution has superseeded the previous brokered solution based on the CEDMiddleware, which has not undergone major updates since the thread you're pointing at (that is, no port of the lightweight Agent to any RTOS has been carried out yet).

We'd be happy to organize a meeting so you can share further details regarding your use-case (e.g. the topology of your bot or your network access possibilities) and we can elaborate more on our solutions. If interested, please contact me at francescafinocchiaro@eprosima.com.

---

Originally posted by [FraFin](https://answers.ros.org/users/68476/frafin/) with karma: 61 on 2021-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toebgen](https://answers.ros.org/users/61046/toebgen/) on 2021-04-21**:
Hi @FraFin and @MisterEd,
we have been trying to find out some more details about the above requested feature.
Are there maybe already any updates on this?
Thank you very much!